# jQuery 1.4 breaks my program

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am pulling html from my database with a jquery ajax request.

However, if there is a single quote ('), I get a parsing error.

Regular quotes work fine (").

For example, in my database I have:

```
style=font-family:"times' new roman"
```

(I put the ' in there after times for testing). With the ' gone it works...

I start the request:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "phps/file.php?id="+id,
       dataType: "json",
       error: function(uno,dos,tres){
```

My php file does:

```
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($results['code']);
//return
header('Content-type: application/x-json');
echo '{';
echo '"code": "' . $code. '"';
echo '}';
```

The jquery error function gives me:

```
[object XMLHttpRequest]
parsererror
undefined
```

I think this is the issue, but I don't know how to fix it:

> We are now strict about incoming JSON and throw an exception if we get malformed JSON.
>   If you need to be able to evaluate malformed JSON that is valid JavaScript, you can make a text request and use eval() to evaluate the contents.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're sending JSON, why aren't you using encode_json?

Comment: Have you tried `json_encode` instead of doing it yourself? - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php . And are you sure you're not looking for `htmlentities` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Note that `style=font-family:"times' new roman"` is not valid HTML attribute declration. HTML attribute values have to be either quoted (unsing single or double quotes) or you can only use the characters `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, `-`, `.`, `_`, and `:` (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).

Answer (score 6):

I would change your PHP to:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('code' => $code));
```

Namely, change the MIME type to `application/json` and use PHP's native [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) rather than manually constructing JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do would be to use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
header('Content-type: application/x-json');
echo json_encode($results);`
```

Or you could replace the " with \" in the string and it should be valid JSON from what I can see.  `str_replace("\"", "\\"", $code)`

Or if neither of those options work, do the text request with jQuery.  I'm not sure on the exact syntax though.

This JSON Validator may prove useful to you: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/